# Spring, Hibernate, transaction management, not committed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

So, I try to use Spring for transaction management. Finally my application had worked, but deleting do not commits. Before using Spring I managed transactions in DAO, and I thought that after I can remove this code. But now deleting do not commit to DB.

My DAO:

```
protected Session getSession() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    ThreadLocalSessionContext.bind(session);
    return session;
}
public void delete(T t) {
    Session session = getSession();
// **this approach I used before**
//  session.beginTransaction();
//  try {
//  session.delete(t);
//  session.getTransaction().commit();
//  } catch (Exception e) {
//      session.getTransaction().rollback();
//  }
    session.delete(t);
    }
```

My applicationContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://ngs-java-srv.synapse.com:3306/mybase" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <!-- <property name="configLocation" value="hibernate.cfg.xml" /> -->

        <property name="packagesToScan" value="todolist.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- dao beans -->
    <bean id="userDao"
        class="todolist.dao.hibernate.UserDaoImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>todolist.entity.User</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="itemDao"
        class="todolist.dao.hibernate.ItemDaoImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>todolist.entity.Item</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- service bean -->
    <bean id="userService" class="todolist.service.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" />
        <property name="itemDao" ref="itemDao" />
    </bean>

    <!-- transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj"/>

    <!-- <tx:annotation-driven/> -->

<!--    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethods"
            expression="execution(* todolist.service.UserService.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceMethods" />
    </aop:config>
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" />
            <tx:method name="deleteItem" no-rollback-for="Exception" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice> -->

    <!-- backbeans -->
    <bean id="userLogin" class="todolist.jsf.UserLogin"
        scope="request">
        <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userLogged" class="todolist.jsf.UserLogged"
        scope="session">
        <aop:scoped-proxy />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userRegister" class="todolist.jsf.UserRegister"
        scope="request">
        <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="createItem" class="todolist.jsf.CreateItem"
        scope="request">
        <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="todoList" class="todolist.jsf.TodoList"
        scope="request">
        <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

UserServiceImpl class

```
package todolist.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import todolist.exception.AuthorizationError;
import todolist.exception.DuplicateLoginsException;
import todolist.service.StringToHashTool;
import todolist.dao.ItemDao;
import todolist.dao.UserDao;
import todolist.entity.Item;
import todolist.entity.User;

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    //private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);

    private UserDao userDao;
    private ItemDao itemDao;

    public void setItemDao(ItemDao itemDao) {
    this.itemDao = itemDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public boolean isUserExists(String login) {
    return (userDao.getUserByLogin(login) != null);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public boolean isPasswordCorrect(String login, String password) {
    if (isUserExists(login)) {
        return userDao.getUserByLogin(login).getPassword()
            .equals(StringToHashTool.getHash(password));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public User login(String login, String password) {
    if (isPasswordCorrect(login, password)) {
        return userDao.getUserByLogin(login);
    } else {
        throw new AuthorizationError("Incorrect password");
    }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public boolean register(String login, String password) {
    if (isUserExists(login)) {
        throw new DuplicateLoginsException("Login " + login + " is already used.");
    } else {
        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin(login);
        user.setPassword(StringToHashTool.getHash(password));
        userDao.save(user);
        return true;
    }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void logout() {

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Item createItem(Long creator_id, Long performer_id,
        String description, Date dueDate) {

    Item item = new Item();
    User user = userDao.getById(creator_id);

    item.setCreator(user);

    user = userDao.getById(performer_id);

    item.setPerformer(user);
    item.setDescription(description);
    item.setStartDate(new Date());
    item.setDueDate(dueDate);

    itemDao.save(item);

    return item;
    }

    @Override    
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void deleteItem(Long item_id) {
    Item item = itemDao.getById(item_id);
    itemDao.delete(item);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public List<Item> getUserItems(String login) {
    User user = userDao.getUserByLogin(login);
    return itemDao.getItemsByPerformer(user.getId());
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public List<User> getUsers() {
    return userDao.getUsers();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<aop:pointcut 
    id="serviceMethods"
    expression="execution(*todolist.service.UserService.*(..))" 
/>
```

First Step:

Change this to:

```
<aop:pointcut 
    id="serviceMethods"
    expression="todolist.service.UserServiceImpl.delete()" 
/>
```

See if delete's start committing. I just want to make sure you flush out any typos and what have you. If this explicit config fails then there must be something wrong with the config.

Comment: Can you provide the whole class? What is UserService an interface?

Comment: I have method deleteItem in my service, that invoke delete in dao, so I wrote expression="(todolist.service.UserServiceImpl.deleteItem(..))", but got an exception: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut deleteItem. Trying to fix now.

Comment: So, I wrote expression="execution(* todolist.service.UserServiceImpl.deleteItem(..))", but comitting doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getCurrentSession` instead of `openSession` in your DAO, so that the getSession method looks like:

```
protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

You're creating a new session that uses a different database connection so the transaction set up for the service doesn't apply.

Also as you have them configured the DAOs will have a default scope of singleton; passing an entity as a constructor-argument doesn't make sense. A singleton shouldn't have instance state specific to some individual transaction.

Comment: Thanks for help. When I changed my getSession(), I got next exception: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction in procedure from UserDaoImpl     public User getUserByLogin(String login) {
 Session session = getSession();
 System.out.println("Session is null: " + (session==null));
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
 criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("login", login));
 return (User) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

Comment: When I changed my getSession(), I got next exception: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction in procedure from UserDaoImpl public User getUserByLogin(String login) { Session session = getSession(); Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);

Comment: I removed  <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> from my configuterion and now application stars well, but when I try to open page, that have to load some collection, a get could "not initialize proxy - no Session"

Comment: And! Adding new records works well now, with committing, so your comment was very useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using the Spring HibernateTransactionManager object and annotation driven configuration.  In my application-context, I simply declare the following two beans:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="session_factory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Then in my service layer, your UserServiceImpl for example:

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

private final UserDao userDao;
private final ItemDao itemDao;

public UserServiceImpl(UserDao userDao, ItemDao itemDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
    this.itemDao = itemDao;
}

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public boolean isUserExists(String login) {
    return (userDao.getUserByLogin(login) != null);
}

...
```

It's important to move you transaction annotations as close to the view (in MVC) as possible.  The reason is 1) performance and 2) atomic transactions.  If the call calling the UserService calls the isUserExists, isPasswordCorrect and login methods in a single function call, you would want those to execute in a single transaction.  To do so, remove the @Transactional annotation from the UserServiceImpl and move it to the calling class.  This ensures that a single transaction is used for all three method calls. For atomic execution, this also works.  Think of the classic bank money transfer example.  If you had two separate transactions on the UserService, the first two method call can succeed and the last one fail. The firt two transactions would be committed because they are in separate transaction blocks which would leave you database in an inconsistent state. Of course, atomic transactions are mostly relevant for transactions that write data.

Also, don't add the transactional annotations to the interfaces, keep them on the implementations.

Then in my DAO, I simply do a sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() and go from there.  getCurrentSession() is thread safe but keep it private to your DAOs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I make changes, that you propose. But my deleting still doesn't committed. Writing data commits well. In my JSF-bean I delete items in loop, may be this is reason?